# How to get an "optimal point" for refinement in FEM adaptive mesh refinement?

Tags: finite-element, reference-request, adaptive-mesh-refinement, poisson-equation

Consider the following 1D problem

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle
-\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} = f(x), \hspace{0.5cm}  x\in (a,b) \\[4mm]
u(a) = u_{a}, \ \ u(b) = u_{b}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

I know how to compute a finite element approximation $u_{h}$ of this problem. I'm working in an h-adaptive method, it works fine but when I refine an element, I divide it in the element midpoint.

I want to refine the element at an "optimal point". Suppose I want to refine the element $I_{k} = [x_{k},x_{k+1}]$. In order to find the "optimal point" $x^{*}\in (x_{k},x_{k+1})$ for the refinement of $I_{k}$, I know that this could be done with the Dual Weighted Residual, that is, we consider the finite element residual

\begin{align*}
R = \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+ f
\end{align*}

and the value $\eta_{k} = r_{k}w_{k}$, that relates the local residual $r_{k}$ and the weight $w_{k}$ (which comes from the dual problem).  But I don't understand how this is related to the optimal point $x^{*}$.

**Do you know how to use these quantities in order to find the point $x^{*}$?**

**Do you know books or articles where I can study this problem?**

Comment: Did you meant to make this a second-order problem? You state it as a first-order problem, but then you can't impose two boundary values.

Comment: Separately, we generally just bisect cells to be refined into equally-sized children. That's easy enough and typically sufficient.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thank you, It is a second-order problem. In response for the last comment, I know that just bisect the cells is simpler but there are cases where the midpoint of the cell is not the best option, I can see that in problems that depend on time.

Comment: Sure, the simple choice is often not the optimal one. The question is whether you can come up with a robust algorithm that does better on all sorts of problems, and automatically. I'm pretty certain that in 1d cases like yours, that wouldn't be too hard to do. But then 1d cases are not hard to solve to begin with -- just take enough cells, it doesn't cost anything after all. The 2d/3d situation is the more interesting one.

Comment: Definitely, the 2d/3d situation is the more interesting one, but for now I'm trying to understand these ideas in the simplest case. My goal for the future is to do this sort of things in 2d/3d.

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp! By intuition, the question of which cells should be subdivided on your global domain is the more interesting one. The choice of a subdivision for each individual cell may give you a miniscule advantage, but as soon as you need to refine again the two, now unequal parts of your subcells will reduce your options naturally. I just don't see how anything could be gained from it on a cell-wise basis.

Comment: What you're trying to do sounds like a mixture of $h$ and $r$ adaptivity. I would suggest you read up on the $r$ adaptivity literature. I will caution that that's an area that was investigated in the 1990s and early 2000s, but hasn't found widespread use. There is probably a good reason for it.